# What is the name of design pattern like "--generate-cli-skeleton" for REST API?

Tags: rest, api

I develop a REST API. I want to provide request parameter through API itself.
The origin of the idea is ["--generate-cli-skeleton" for aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-skeleton.html).

Do you know any name or example about the way to return request parameter for REST API endpoints?

For example, add special request header to show needing skeleton like this.

`curl -X POST -H "Generate-Skeleton: True" https://exmaple.com/users`
→ `{name: "", age: ""}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic question im my head remains: Why do you need it?

In my opinion in terms of REST this sounds like an anti-pattern. REST is a generalization of the browsable Web targeting on machines rather than humans, though the same concepts that apply to the Web basically apply also to applications that follow a REST architecture.

Plenty of CRUD services allow to create new resources via `POST` requests. Here the semantic of the payload is defined by the server. A client either needs out-of-band information on how to create such a payload or the server needs to teach a client such information somehow. On the Web this is done via forms. A form defines not only the required data input but also where to send the payload to. The same can be done in applications following a REST architectural style. Here a form should be described as own media-type that both server and clients use and understand, similar to HTML which server and browers know and understand. In absence of a dedicated media-type representing a form that can be used in a REST architecture, one can simply reuse HTML's form capabilities i.e.

Retrieving the data from the server should also avoid interpreting the resource being of a particular type. This easily can fool you into the [typed resource trap](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). Instead `content-type negotiation` should be used where a clients informs the server about its capabilities and the server attempts to respond with a representation the client can make some use of. In regards to the above mentioned form example, a client and server could agree on something like a `application/form+json` representation where the server basically returns similar information as for HTML forms, just in JSON syntax. Care should be taken on custom media types however. They should be as generic as possible to be applicable to plenty clients else chances are high that the support for such media types will be quite limited.

Together with HATEOAS, which basically adds the support for [link-relation names](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) and avoids parsing and interpreting URIs but only uses them to invoke the next operation on the targeted endpoint, these are the fundamental prerequisists IMO a REST architecture imposes on both clients and servers in order to gain a high degree of decoupling, freedom on the server side to evole without having to fear breaking clients and making clients more robust towards change.

On applying these steps a resource becomes pretty much self-describing. There is no real need for external documentation or other out-of-band information if done right or the need for client based stub/skeletton classes to interact with the API as in the end URI and HTTP are the necessary interfaces clients need to support.

If you need to support custom headers the server needs to inform a client in the absence of those that it expexts them. This is similar to i.e. Basic Authentication. A client sends a request to the server and the server responds with a `401 Unauthorized` response containing a header such as `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="fooBar"` which informs the client that the server is expecting basic authentication with the mention realm. Plenty of client implementation know that a user and password/key are required in a form like `username:password` that further needs to be base64 encoded and appended to a `Basic` string. This is usually often done in the back without much input from your side. For a custom header this might, however, not that easy to automate. But you still could issue appropriate error codes such as `409 Conflict` or `422 Unprocessable Entity` to inform a client of a required but missing header. Such custom headers would be best described in media-types though as they include both the syntactical as well as the semantical description on the representations exchanged, including optional headers.

If you need to generate such properties in order to generate client-stub code or configuration you are almost likely not to have a REST but more of a RPC like system that is tailor-made to interact with your API but would fail on any other endpoint. Such client-side code might, depending on its internals, break easily though if you change i.e. your URI structure or somethin within a message format exchanged. This is also very similar to SOAP/WSDL client-stub code generation where one could retrieve the  WSDL XML representation of the service, generate some stub classes and then implement against these inferfaces. Problem here usually was, that if something was modified in the WSDL file after the client-stub code was generated, clients needed to regenerate the stub-classes and eventually update their client-code to interact with the interfaces created. This is especially cumbersome if the only channel you gain update information from is one that you do not frequently visit (i.e. the maintainers homepage). In most cases you witness the problem only when the service got already updated. This happend to us back a couple of years ago a couple of times which forced us to push out some updates to applications deployed on various client machines which cost us a couple of man-days to update these.

I hope you can see why I consider this as an anti-pattern in terms of REST where a server should inform a client with all the stuff it needs to take further actions or provide a way for a client to provide missing information and sent it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using something like json-schema instead?

If you do want some kind of JSON template for requests, they should not live on the same uri, accessed by a resource.

Instead, you should make a separate part of your API, for example:

```
GET /templates/user <- to fetch a 'skeleton' as you call it
```

To discover these templates, you could create links from tactical places in your existing API. This could be a `Link:` header somewhere that points to a relevant template.

Comment: > they should not live on the same uri, accessed by a resource
I agree to the design. Link header also looks convinient.